# contiki on STM32F4

Tags: contiki, stm32f4discovery

I'm starting a development with contiki and STM32F4discovery.

I found a fork of contiki for STM32F4discovery from jensnielsen on github.

I've downloaded it and try to make for the TARGET STM32F4discovery using
make TARGET=stmf4discovery hello-world

The makefile just compile hellow-world.c and then fail when it try to link the project because it doesn't find the reference of contiki core, sys, etc.

I try to make the hello-world in native and it works find.

What do I have to do to make the target?

Best regards,

Pascal

Answer (score 1):

This is a very narrow question on my personal code, you should probably have asked me directly rather than stack overflow...

But anyway, the answer to the question is that my port is incomplete and broken, you should go for another fork (perhaps https://github.com/ptasz3k/contiki-stm32f4discovery)